# Problema de crear un tabla en javascript como las que tiene cabecera todo

Tags: javascript, html, tablas

estos son los datos que deseo agregar a la tabla

```
var etnias =[
             {departamento : "Raccs", ciudad:"Bluefiels", etnia: "Mestizos"},
             {departamento : "Raccs", ciudad:"Laguna de perlas", etnia: "Creolle"},
             {departamento : "Raccs", ciudad:"El Rama", etnia: "Mestizos"},
             {departamento : "Raccs", ciudad:"Bilwi", etnia: "Miskito"}
             ];



for(var i =0; i<= etnias.length-1; i++)
{




    //console.log(etnias[i].departamento);
}


console.log(etnias);
```

como ven hasta ahi quede la otra forma fue en el index.html

#
            Departamento
            Ciudad/Comunidad
            Etnia

```
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Raccs</td>
        <td>Bluefields</td>
        <td>Meztisos</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

que ahi si me sale pero en el javascript me pueden ayudar porfa.

Comment: Por favor redacta títulos objetivos, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

una solución a este problema es usando los métodos InsertRow y InsertCell, estos se encargaran de insertar los nodos de el elemento TBODY

Para la lectura de array de objetos, se esta usando un bucle, hay otras funciones que lo pueden minimizar. Por otro lado, momento de ubicarme en un objeto, lo he tenido que convertir en un array, para ello use el método entries de la clase Object, dando este tres array con dos valores, el  primero con el nombre clave del objeto y el segundo el valor de este, en cada uno. Mi idea era integrar un tag Name a cada elemento td y que tenga como valor la palabra clave:

```
<tr>
<td name="departamento"></td>
<td name="ciudad"></td>
<td name="etnia"></td>
```

Pero eso ya te lo dejo de tarea.

```js
 var etnias = [
      { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Bluefiels", etnia: "Mestizos" },
      { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Laguna de perlas", etnia: "Creolle" },
      { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "El Rama", etnia: "Mestizos" },
      { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Bilwi", etnia: "Miskito" },
    ];

    const tabla = document
      .querySelector("#tablita")
      .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];


    for (let i = 0; i < etnias.length; i++) {
       let z = tabla.insertRow(i).insertCell(0);
      let items = Object.entries(etnias[i])
      items.map((x)=>{
        let td = document.createElement("td")
        td.innerHTML = x[1]
        z.appendChild(td);
      })
    }
```

```html
 <table id="tablita">
          <tbody>
           
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Te recomiendo leer la documentación:**

- [Clase object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object)
- [Método Entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries)
- [Método InsertRow()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)
- [Método InsertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

Answer (score 0):

1.- Si lo que deseas es crear una tabla con los datos que se encuentran en `etnias` lo recomendable es recorrer este arreglo y cada vez que lo recorras crear un **template literal** e insertarlos en el `tbody`.

2.- El codigo quedaria de esta manera:

```
var etnias = [
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Bluefiels", etnia: "Mestizos" },
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Laguna de perlas", etnia: "Creolle" },
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "El Rama", etnia: "Mestizos" },
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Bilwi", etnia: "Miskito" },
];
```

Recorremos etnias y creamos el template literal por cada elemento recorrido

```
etnias.forEach((element) => {

 //ACCEDEMOS AL TBODY DE TU TABLA Y LE INSERTAMOS UN NUEVO TR

  document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML += `<tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>${element.departamento}</td>
          <td>${element.ciudad}</td>
          <td>${element.etnia}</td>
        </tr>`;
});
```

```js
var etnias = [
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Bluefiels", etnia: "Mestizos" },
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Laguna de perlas", etnia: "Creolle" },
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "El Rama", etnia: "Mestizos" },
  { departamento: "Raccs", ciudad: "Bilwi", etnia: "Miskito" },
];

//CONTROLAS EL INCREMENTO DE CADA ITEM
let contador = 1;

etnias.forEach((element) => {
  document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML += `<tr>
          <td>${contador++}</td>
          <td>${element.departamento}</td>
          <td>${element.ciudad}</td>
          <td>${element.etnia}</td>
        </tr>`;
});
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody ></tbody>
 </table>
```

Leer mas sobre template literals:

[plantillas de cadenas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)